# Is it possible to add multiple security groups while creating ALB

Tags: aws-cdk

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_elasticloadbalancingv2/ApplicationLoadBalancer.html

ALB CDK has an attribute to return the list of security groups but couldn't find a way to add a list of security groups while creating ALB. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Hello, did you manage to solve the issue? If so, please share.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your use case for the security group. This may work - just put it in a loop for multiple security groups:

```
myAlb.connections.addSecurityGroup(mySG)
```

---

EDIT:

There's actually a ticket for this.

> https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/5138

Here is a workaround:

```
myElb;  // ELB created elsewhere in code

// get the CfnLoadBalancer from the LoadBalancer object
const cfnElb = myElb.node.defaultChild as elb.CfnLoadBalancer  

// View SG list before the addition
console.log(cfnAdminELB.securityGroups)

// SecurityGroups can be 'undefined' need to check so that you don't get a warning
if (cfnElb.securityGroups){ 
    cfnElb.securityGroups.push(mySecurityGroup.securityGroupId)
}

// Verify the token is added
console.log(cfnAdminELB.securityGroups)
```

In theory, you could delete things from the cfnElb.securityGroups list too if you wanted to get rid of their default CDK creates.